# How does the AWS Inteface VPC endpoint actually route traffic to regional service?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

When I configure an AWS Gateway VPC endpoint, a route table entry is created that points to the Gateway. Here, Gateway can be thought of performing the routing to AWS service (over private network).

However, for an AWS Inteface VPC endpoint, all that is visible is a Network interface that has a private IP address of the subnet. By default, a private IP can send traffic within the subnet or entire VPC provided Security Group and NACL allows the traffic. & it appears in this case there is no Route table entry to a Gateway or a Router for allowing traffic outside VPC.

> How / Where is the interface routing the traffic to i.e. How does traffic leave the customer VPC?

Of course I understand that the traffic finally reaches the intended AWS service over private network but here I am trying to find out where is the Gateway or Router? Does AWS hide this implementation?

I cannot get my head around the fact that a simple Network Interface can accept traffic and route it to a service all by itself i.e. performing routing by itself? Clearly, in this case the traffic appears not flowing through the VPC router or another Gateway device.

I am aware this might be an AWS confidential implementation but any thoughts / idea on how they might have designed this feature?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It doesn't provide routing at all, by default a VPC interface endpoint when created will create an ENI per subnet in the VPC for you. It will also provide you a DNS name per each AZ and a global name that you can use within your applications.

In addition it supports the ability to have the AWS service domain name for the VPC interface endpoint be resolvable to the private IPs of the endpoint. As long as your VPC has DNS enabled it will first check the VPC private DNS resolver and then resolve it to the private IP rather than the public one.

This is done by adding an additional [private hosted zone](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/hosted-zones-private.html) to your VPC which resolves service domains in your region such as `ec2.us-east-1.amazonaws.com`.

[image]

From the AWS side this is just an ENI created in your AWS VPC that is connected to one of AWS internal VPCs. It's actually possible to implement this for your own services too to share with another organisations VPCs, this is implemented using [AWS PrivateLink](https://aws.amazon.com/privatelink/).

For more information take a look at the [Private DNS for interface endpoints](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpce-interface.html#vpce-private-dns) page.

Comment: Thanks Chris Williams - On your comment -"This is just an ENI created in your AWS VPC that is connected to one of AWS internal VPCs" - I think I am looking for clarity here - Generally, it is VPC peering that makes this kind of stuff work. Is it possible to connect 2 VPCs just by an ENI - How does that work? - can you explain.

Comment: So PrivateLink enables a ENI to be created in your AWS VPC that is bound to an NLB in another AWS Account. What happens under the hood in the networking layer is behind closed doors, but essentially this is what is happening. Similar functionality also happens for services like RDS, the host lives in an AWS private account but an ENI gets created in your account so that you can communicate with it :)

Comment: Cheers again; things getting clearer :-) One last question - When you say ENI is "bound" to an NLB or RDS, do you mean the ENI accepts traffic on its Private address and has some "magical capability" to send / route the same traffic to a completely different network address? This for me appears to be some inbuilt routing capability within the ENI - Can the usual ENI that I create in AWS do this? Or is it only these special kind of PrivateLink ENIs that has this capability?

Comment: What I mean is there's some kind of attachment from the ENI to NLB, it is indeed connected although you can only see your VPCs side of that connection. The how it is connected it PrivateLink, as far as I am aware you cannot create an ENI in another VPC and bind it to an AWS resource in your VPC but you can create your own VPC endpoints which use exactly the same functionality. Whatever happens on the PrivateLink part is open to speculation but it will essentially translate the private IP of the ENI to a private IP of the target resource I would imagine.

Comment: The magic on the other side of the ENI is handled by the network function virtualization platform called [AWS Hyperplane](https://youtu.be/dfEcd3zqPOA?t=4661), which also powers NAT Gateway and Network Load Balancer.

Comment: I just read about AWS Hyperplane and yeah, many reinvents dig deep into the fundamentals - Thanks @Michael - sqlbot for pointing me to the right references.

Comment: Is it possible (may be using rout tables) to make traffic to do not leave AZ when I send a request to the global DNS name? Now it is randomly distributes traffic across all AZ where VPC Endpoint is registered. In our case (50-100TB/month) it generates a lot of cross-AZ paid traffic.