# Cannot connect to AWS Sagemaker from a lambda deployed in a VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker, amazon-vpc, vpc-endpoint

I have deployed a AWS Lambda function within a private subnet in VPC. I created a VPC endpoints/s for Sagemaker in the same private subnet and then tried to do inference from Sagemaker. In the route table attached to the private subnet I have an entry to the local VPC (and S3 VPC endpoint). But, the request to Sagemaker gets timeout. I have used a separate security group for VPC and point and allowed all inbound traffic from the lambda function and the lambda function is connected to a security group allowing all the out bound traffic to the VPC endpoint security group.

When I add `0.0.0.0/0 -> to NAT in public subnet` it works and make the call through the NAT. What am I missing here?

1. Should I add any routes for the Sagemaker VPC endpoint in the route table?
2. Or assign a public IP to the ENI of the VPC endpoint?
3. Or add a route to some path to the ENI of the VPC endpoint?

Should I provide any endpoint URL in when I deploy the model or predict in my Python script of the lambda function (I found a [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76177398/lambda-invocations-from-a-vpc-dont-go-through-the-vpc-interface-endpoint-for-la?rq=2) solution for a problem with the lambda interface. They explicitly provided the `endpoint_url` to the VPC endpoint.

Comment: Do you have DNS support enabled on the VPC?

Comment: @MarkB yes, the `DNS resolution` is enabled

Comment: I would suggest confirming you can dig `https://runtime.sagemaker.<YourRegion>.amazonaws.com` and its resolving to a private IP and then curl to confirm you can connect. Something is misconfigured at a networking level. May be worth while launching an ec2 instance with same subnet and security group as lambda to troubleshoot from.